# Published reference for the term "unitor" of monoidal categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am writing a report about monoidal categories which in particular contains a definition of monoidal categories and thus the term "unitor" for the natural isomorphisms $I \otimes X \cong X$ and $X \otimes I \cong X$.

I thought that this choice of terminology was "folklore" (it is for example used on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) and [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unitor)), but my professor doesn't seem to be familiar with the usage of the word "unitor" for these morphisms. They want me to add a *published* reference for it. (I looked into "MacLane's Categories for the Working Mathematician", but it looks like in there these morphims are called just $\lambda$ and $\rho$.) Could someone point to a reference for this terminology?

Comment: Just Google unitor monoidal. References come up eventually.